# Convert types of certain columns of data frames in a list

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert every column in the data frame apart from the first to numeric type, I have tried:

```
frames<-lapply(frames,function(x) {x[,2:ncol(x)]<-as.numeric(as.character(x[,2:ncol(x)]))} )
```

however this is replacing everything with NAs

Have also tried

```
frames<-lapply(frames,function(x) {x[,2:ncol(x)]<-as.numeric(as.character(unlist(x[,2:ncol(x)]))  ) } )
```

However this attempt did not preserve the structure of the frames

Code to create an equivalent dataset:

```
 test<-data.frame(Col1=c(1,2,3,4), Col2=c(2,4,5,5) , Col3=c(245,51,23,5) )
 test2<-data.frame(Col1= c(1,3,1,4), Col2= c(2,3,5,6) ,Col3= c(2,51,23,5))
 test[,2:3]<- lapply(test[,2:3], as.factor)
 test2[,2:3]<- lapply(test2[,2:3], as.factor)
 test_list<-list(test,test2)
```

Now that the two frames are in test_list, I would like to convert the second and third columns of each test data frame to be numeric type.

A sample of my dataset produced by `dput(frames[[1]][1:5,1:5])`

```
 structure(list(date = c("04/03/13 - 10/03/13", "11/03/13 - 17/03/13",     
 "18/03/13 -   24/03/13", "25/03/13 - 31/03/13", "01/04/13 - 07/04/13"    ), 
`Summary Z: ` = c("12",     "9", "12", "10", "13"), `Summary O: ` = c("24",   
 "28", "24", "15", "17"), `Summary M: ` = c("3",     "4", "3", "2", "1"), 
 `Summary S: ` = c("2",     "2", "6", "3", "4")), .Names = c("date", "Summary Z: ",
 "Summary O: ",     "Summary M: ",     "Summary S: "    ), row.names = 7:11,
 class =   "data.frame")
```

Comment: You should use `frames[,-1] <- lapply(frames[,-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Comment: @akrun This produces error " Error in frames[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions "

Comment: @use1987097 Sorry, I didn't test it. Could you show an example to test it?

Comment: @akrun What do you mean, an example of what?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the list of dataframes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `lapply` within the `list` to convert the `factor` columns to `numeric`.  In the example provided, except the `first` column, all others need to be converted to `numeric`.  In the code below, unselect column 1  by `x[,-1]`.  By using `lapply(x,[,-1],..)`, it converts those columns to `numeric` in a list.  Assigning `<-` to `x[,-1]` restores the original `data.frame` structure for the converted columns.  In the last step, `return(x)` or just `x` will return the `x` data.frame within the list.

```
 res <-  lapply(frames, function(x) {
             x[,-1] <- lapply(x[,-1], function(.x) as.numeric(as.character(.x)))
                   x})


 lapply(res,head,2)
 # [[1]]
 #  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 #1  N 10 19 15  8  7
 #2  O 15  3 17  9  7

 # [[2]]
 #  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 #1  K  1 12 14 13 13
 #2  O  3  4  1  5 17
```

Using the `test_list` dataset

```
 res2 <- lapply(test_list, function(x) {
            x[,-1] <- lapply(x[,-1], function(.x) as.numeric(as.character(.x)))
                  x})



 str(res2)
 # List of 2
 #$ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 # ..$ Col1: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
 #..$ Col2: num [1:4] 2 4 5 5
 #..$ Col3: num [1:4] 245 51 23 5
 #$ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 #..$ Col1: num [1:4] 1 3 1 4
 #..$ Col2: num [1:4] 2 3 5 6
 #..$ Col3: num [1:4] 2 51 23 5
```

#### Update

Using the `dput` output

```
 frames <- structure(list(date = c("04/03/13 - 10/03/13", "11/03/13 - 17/03/13",     
 "18/03/13 -   24/03/13", "25/03/13 - 31/03/13", "01/04/13 - 07/04/13"    ), 
`Summary Z: ` = c("12",     "9", "12", "10", "13"), `Summary O: ` = c("24",   
"28", "24", "15", "17"), `Summary M: ` = c("3",     "4", "3", "2", "1"), 
`Summary S: ` = c("2",     "2", "6", "3", "4")), .Names = c("date", "Summary Z: ",
"Summary O: ",     "Summary M: ",     "Summary S: "    ), row.names = 7:11,
 class =   "data.frame")

 frameslist <- list(frames, frames)
 frameslist <- lapply(frameslist, function(x) {
                          x[,-1] <- lapply(x[,-1], as.numeric)
                                x})

 str(frameslist[[1]])
 #'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
 #$ date       : chr  "04/03/13 - 10/03/13" "11/03/13 - 17/03/13" "18/03/13 -   24/03/13" "25/03/13 - 31/03/13" ...
 # $ Summary Z: : num  12 9 12 10 13
 # $ Summary O: : num  24 28 24 15 17
 # $ Summary M: : num  3 4 3 2 1
 # $ Summary S: : num  2 2 6 3 4
```

Comment: I think this deleted the first column of every data frame

Comment: @user1987097 It didn't delete any column.  I was selecting all other columns except the first one `x[,-1]` to convert to `numeric`

Comment: What purpose does the trailing x serve?

Comment: @user1987097 It is to return the dataframe `x`. If you don't use it, then the result will be a list of `lists` with the nested list elements occupied by the columns selected for conversion

Comment: I just tried to run this it's giving me  : error unexpected symbol

Comment: @user1987097 I tried this code on two datasets (one you created) and it works well in both cases.  Are you copy/pasting the code directly?

Comment: Ok it appears to be an oddity in the dataset I'm working with.

Comment: @user1987097 Could you show the `dput` output of a subset of your dataset. ie. `dput(head(dataset, 10))`

Comment: The output is too large

Comment: @user1987097 If it is a list `dput(lapply(lst, function(x) droplevels(x[1:5,1:5]))[1:2])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63474/discussion-between-user1987097-and-akrun).

Comment: In the end I just modified the original solution you provided : 

.... as.numeric(as.character(.x))) ;return( x)})